# Can i use "for" in it-infinitvals after "want"?

Tags: grammar

Does contemporary English grammar allow to use Subordinator «for» after «want» when constructing to-Infinitivals
If so, is there any limitations on such a use?

a)  We want for them to be engaged learners.

b)  I want for them to be able to follow their dreams.

c)  The only thing you want for them to do is to be fair.

Huddleston and Pullum’s  grammar book explicitly states that "for" after "want"  is permitted only if Adjunct is inserted before subordinator "for".

d)  They had wanted **all along** for the performance to begin at 6.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: All four sentences are *grammatically correct*. In the first three sentences, "for" is unnecessary, so it should be left out for *better style*, which I think is what your grammar book means by "permitted". The fourth sentence is 100% natural.

Comment: I don't think you'd lose any marks for the first 3 sentences on a standardized English test since native speakers talk and write that way, but in an academic literature essay, for instance, it would be marked down. A novel's editor would get rid of the first three "for"s.

Comment: Page number, please.

Comment: the book is out of reach, i will find it and post it later.

Comment: a) to c) are ungrammatical. The reason is that in the case of the verb "want", "them" is not subject of the infinitival clause but object of the matrix clause (i.e. object of "want), so "for" must be excluded.

Comment: BillJ, page 1180, Pullum, sorry was a bit busy for sending the message earlier

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it may come across differently.

Saying "**[want for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want%20for)**" expresses being without or lacking that which is wanted, so you saying, "We want for them to be engaged learners," is definitively suggestive of *them **not** being engaged learners*, that *them being engaged learners* is something "we" *lack* or *are without*.

That isn't to say that if you omit "for" by instead saying, "We want them to be engaged learners," it can't be taken the same way. That's because various meanings of "**[want](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want)**" are suggestive of that. What's key, though, is OTHER MEANINGS ARE NOT, very commonly used meanings. So, a prudent listener won't go so far as to assume that "we" are without *them being engaged learners* but instead will only go so far as to take it to mean that *them being engaged learners* is something desirous. Unless otherwise expressed, it would be jumping to conclusions to automatically infer that "want" alone (without "for") in that context means *them being engaged learners* is something "we" are without because the most we can be sure of based on "want" alone there is that it's something "we" desire (e.g., something desirous we have and wish to keep).

***However***, since the phrasal verb "want for" is to be used solely to expressly convey being without whatever follows "for," know that that is what you're saying when you say "want for," which is beyond merely saying it's desirous, which is what "want" often means and all you can reliably take "want" to mean without further foundation.

Now, is there overlap? Yes. Are there people who misuse "want for" not intending to suggest lacking or being without whatever is wanted for? Yes. Are there also people who will infer "want for" as simply conveying what follows as being desirous and not necessarily conveying lacking or being without it? Yes. There will always be those who misuse terms and who are imprecise in their speech. That doesn't change the fact of the matter, though, that "want for," by definition, is strictly for conveying lacking or being without that which is wanted, while "want" is not.

**BRASS TACKS:**

*While "want" can mean "want for," can mean being without or lacking that which is wanted, it doesn't always, so unless your intention is expressly to convey being without or lacking that which is wanted, don't use "want for" but use "want" instead.*

Comment: "want for" does not always indicate lack, consider "*A good life is what I want for them.*".

Answer (score 0):

In my view, a sentence such as

> We want for them to be engaged learners.

Is unusual and will sound odd to a fluent or native speaker.

The reason for this is that there are several meanings of "want". The most commonly used meaning is "to desire or to wish for". An older, now less common meaning is "to lack, to be in need of".

The phrasal verb "want for" is normally used only with teh "lack" meaning. A classic example is "She wants for nothing", meaning that he has everything that she might need. See the definitions by [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/want-for) and by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/want-for-something)

But in the example sentences, "want for" is used in the sense of "desire". That seems off, although a fluent speaker will probably understand it, perhaps after a pause to rethink. But better would be:

> (A1) We want them to be engaged learners.

If the speaker wants to stress that the students are not (yet) engaged learners, as [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/291215/91457) suggests, it si better if that is said directly, rather than trying to express it by a trick of grammar:

> (A2) We want them to be engaged learners, but they aren't yet.

Similarly the for should be omitted from b, giving:

> (B1) I want them to be able to follow their dreams.

Similarly, use

> (C1) The only thing you want them to do is to be fair.

However, "want for" is often used when it is not follow ed by an infinitive, as in:

> (D) A good life is what I want for them.

I would advise avoiding the older sense of "want". It will sound stilted or old-fashioned.